# Building webservices and integrating an ESB for an ASP.Net application?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, esb, mule

We have an ASP.Net C# application that requires some form of a web services implementation for integration with other applications. Currently we have been looking at servicestack and also using an ESB e.g. Mule.

I am trying to figure out the best way to integrate an ESB like Mule into our ASP.Net application.

Do we need to build a web service into our ASP.Net application so that an ESB can integrate with it?

If yes what would be a good approach for selecting a web service type (e.g. REST, WCF, SOAP, Servicestack) that will be compatible with an ASP.Net application and Mule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do we need to build a web service into our ASP.Net application so that
>   an ESB can integrate with it?

Usually it's the other way around. An integration middleware, like Mule, speaks tons of protocols just for the sake of being able to connect to existing systems without changing them.

> If yes what would be a good approach for selecting a web service type
>   (e.g. REST, WCF, SOAP, Servicestack) that will be compatible with an
>   ASP.Net application and Mule?

If your application has really no pre-existing channel you could use to integrate with (not even a simple web form HTTP POST? really?) and you want to expose an API so an integration middleware can connect to it, pick the architecture/technology that maps to the API style you're creating (REST for a resource oriented API, SOAP for a RPC oriented API).

Comment: There are web forms pages (.aspx) so I suppose that the ESB could then post data to these pages? I am not too familiar with this concept. I always assumed the best way to provide integration with external systems was through web services APIs e.g. REST/SOAP.

Comment: Of course but sometimes you can't modify the running system: this is when an ESB's capacity to speak many protocols comes handy. But if it is part of your plan to create an API for your app, then do it and use it.

Comment: The original idea was that we would use an ESB instead of creating an API. I did some research and concluded that the best way to connect the ESB to our Application was by using an API. However if it is possible to use the form post approach then I think this would be the easiest way to go about it.

Comment: I would definitively first try integrating the application as is and only if it turns out impossible resolves to modify the application.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds backwards. What are you required to integrate with, and what capabilities are you trying to provide?

A web service is decoupled from its implementation, you would choose to use a web service if you're trying to expose your system capabilities in an interoperable way so that it's accessible by a broad range of clients.

What you do within a web service is up to you, i.e. you could then for example connect with your ESB. Nothing is precludes you from doing that. ServiceStack also supports hosting from within an existing ASP.NET (or MVC application) see the [Hello World example](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/) for different ways of configuring ServiceStack.

REST / RPC has to do with the design of your web services and [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) supports both models. i.e. inherit from **RestServiceBase** if you want to provide different implementations when the service is invoked with different HTTP Verbs. Inherit **ServiceBase** if you want the same implementation to be used no matter how it was invoked. [This article](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) shows the difference between REST vs RPC/SOAP - and how you can support both in ServiceStack.

So if your exposing a single operation (or want to support SOAP) use **ServiceBase**, if your exposing a 'Resource' where you want to allow it to be managed using different HTTP Verbs use **RestServiceBase**.

Comment: We want to integrate with other esbs so we figure implementing our own is the best approach. So is implementing a webservice the best way to integrate with an esb?

Comment: As mythz says, this is backwards. The ESB integrates with your application, not the other way around. The ESB can integrate at any level using different approaches: web tier, API, database, messaging, files in directories...

Comment: Ok but with this asp.net application in its current form how can the an ESB integrate with it?

Comment: @lanks a web service can be used like a facade to de-couple clients so they can participate in your ESB without taking on the ESB dependency. The 2 technologies are not related in anyway, a webservice can take an outside request and push it to your ESB. It goes back to what you're trying to achieve - as to whether this is the desired approach or not. i.e. Why do you want to integrate an ESB into your app? is it existing? or required?

Comment: @lanks it could be has simple as an HTTP application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST to one of your existing form handler. Or a direct connection to your app's DB.

Comment: @mythz The ESB is not existing. We are looking at using one as an alternative to building a webservice into our application. What we want to do is initiate conversations with other systems (e.g. other ESB's) through our ASP.Net application. For example a user makes a payment in our ASP.Net application and a notification gets sent to an ESB at another company in real time.

Comment: The idea is that our ESB will integrate with our ASP.Net application then other ESB's will go through our ESB to integrate rather than directly to our ASP.Net application.

Comment: Thanks for the extra context. I'd say pick the style (REST/SOAP) you're most familiar with and have your ESB expose internal services for your ASP.NET app and external ones for the remote ESBs. If the ESB needs to call your ASP.NET app, try first to use the existing integration points (HTTP layer, DB) before adding specific services in it.

Comment: @lanks I agree with David I'd create an HTTP (REST/RPC) web service facade over both yours + external ESB impls. The service can can accept the order and drop it into their internal ESB system.